# Is the Pod Racing location real?

Tags: star-wars, film-location, the-phantom-menace

In the Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace, when Anakin participates in the Pod race on Tatooine we can see the big location of the race starting point. I know these buildings are fake. So my question is, where was this scene shot? Did they use studios (animated) or a real location to shoot this scene?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wide shots were done in Tunisia.  However, much of it was done on a miniature set using practical effects, supplemented with CG (Blue Screen) for the final cut.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find this location:
Sidi Bouhlel, Tozeur, Tunisia 
according to  [Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace (1999)
Filming Locations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/locations)

And on the Wikipedia page [List of Star Wars filming locations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_filming_locations)

there are various locations in Tunisia which were used for the Tatooine scenes.

those are just the locations i know, but i think the sets were built, with the crowd and all other manner of alien life was done with CGI. the buildings look a little too "real" to be CGI, given that time (1999), hence they were built.